# Configuring a scheduled task to run whether or not a user is logged in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm setting up scheduled tasks in Windows Server 2016 through Powershell (not through `schtasks.exe`).

```
$user = "Administrator"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 0:00 
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\forfiles.exe" -Argument '/p "C:\example"'
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -User $user -TaskName "foobar"
```

The tasks do not run.  `Run only if user is logged in` is enabled on the new tasks.  I want to try to see if the tasks run if `Run whether user is logged in or not` is enabled.

I don't see anything in the [New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasksettingsset?view=windowsserver2022-ps) regarding this.

Is there a way to do this through Powershell?

Comment: If you want to run as logged in or not, then it can't run in the context of the user. It needs to run as system, not administrator. To do this, you can remove your `$user` line, add this line: `$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest` and then in the register statement, remove `-user $user` and replace with `-Principal $principal`

Comment: Please note, you may want to try running as `NT AUTHORITY\LocalSYSTEM` first before trying `SYSTEM` as localsystem has lesser privileges.

Comment: I think `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService` could work as well. You will need to run PowerShell as administrator.

Comment: Scheduled tasks **can** run in user context, but you need to provide the password for it to log on with. Use the same `Register-ScheduledTask` command as in the question, and just add `-Password "password"` for the associated user.

Comment: @Narzard I think OPs question is to mimic the UI setting where you can indeed select your current user, and have it run as that user without being logged in. It can even run without storing the password (the UI has a checkbox to allow not storing the password)

Answer (score 0):

Following [Narzard's guidance](https://superuser.com/questions/1820405/configuring-a-scheduled-task-to-run-whether-or-not-a-user-is-logged-in-powershel#comment2865209_1820405) - I am using this with success:

```
$user = "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 0:00 
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\foobar.exe" -Argument '/baz "buzz"'
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -User $user -TaskName "foobarbazbuzz" -Description "These tasks run"
```

There are some details on what this `$user` account signifies over at https://serverfault.com/questions/168752/windows-localsystem-vs-system.